# await of multiple server responses

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have data to get from server, but in one response i can get only N rows (but i need all of it, account can have 10N, or 1000N of rows), and amount of rows is unknown before i get first response (wich contains amount of N's), my logic is depend on this data, wich means i need to wait load and only then do my stuff, i see 3 ways:

1. Loop / recursion with async: false, but i cant use this, cause app policy
2. sth like setInterval(handler, 500) and flag is loading ended
3. i send first request and depend on data getted creatring promises to get other parts, await all of it and then do my stuff

But i hope in modern js we have some better ways to solve problems like this

Comment: Why do you need _all_ the rows upfront?  Why not use like an "infinite scroll" thing, where you get the rows as you need them?

Comment: i need it all cause my app logic depends on it, i provide interface to CRUD operation on entities, that depend on it

Comment: some of [these posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+asyncunfold) will be helpful to you. if you get stuck, tell me where and i can try to help more.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). It's modern and made just for promises (asyncs/awaits as well).

Comment: i dont know promises amount before i get first response

Comment: Ooooh... I think there's no pre-built function for that. I simply used a plain old loop in my nodejs script that had to do basically the same thing: https://github.com/overlisted/discord-messages-fetch/blob/main/index.js

Comment: this should have been posted as a comment on the original post

Comment: Do I have to copy it over there now?

Comment: my current solution is way 3 in question, i hoped there is some better ways to solve problems like this, but if not, i think question answered